# What is better design approach for RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have been playing around with `RabbitMQ` for last couple of weeks and developed the following design pattern

`producer <--> Exchange <---> queues <---> consumer.`

I have used couple of RabbitMQ clients like `EasyNetQ` and `MassTransit`. Both clients work with my above design however one thing common between them is that if an `Exchange` doesn't exist it creates one and similarly if a queue doesn't exist then it creates one accordingly.

However, I am thinking creating exchange, queues and binding from either producer or consumers a good design approach?

Is it more meaningful to create the exchange and queues within the RabbitMQ Management manually? Then prevent Producer and Consumer from creating the above in the code?

But I am more concerned what if the exchanges and queues are deleted then it also breaks the producer and consumers?

What do you suggest guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CD (Continuous Deployment)  for both producer and consumer should be responsible of creating these resources, your CD should check for the existence of resource and create if it doesn't exist.

You should avoid creating/deleting resources from code, producer and consumer should really just publish/consume, if you are using a cloud provider, code shouldn't be authorized to manipulate resources at all.

The way I would do it:

- Info of Exchanges/Queues used by consumer/producer should be read from settings file.
- When deployment starts, CD should create the required exchanges/queues.
- CD should then override settings through environment variables.
- Producer/Consumer will then deal with resources info fed by CD, this way CD can make sure that both parties are using same queue/exchange info.

Also you will be making the risk of miscommunication, resource over usage, and resource manipulation (like deleting a queue!) less.

In production, Nothing/No one should be authorized to edit resources except for few people who really know what they are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestion Yahya. Sorry for being ignorant but what is CD?

Comment: Please google CI/CD, basically CD is a short for continuous deployment, where you have an automated process of deployment that is triggered after your code is successfully merged and built and unit tested.

Comment: Ahright I see. Yes am aware of Continuous Integration :) Wasn't sure about the acronym CD :)

Comment: I see rabbitmq has the ability to manage this https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe the question has two parts. I will try taking each one separately:

**Topology**

On your diagram, your producer puts messages to the queue of a consumer. It simply doesn't work with RabbitMQ:

> The core idea in the messaging model in RabbitMQ is that the producer never sends any messages directly to a queue.
>   (from the docs)

Therefore, as you noticed, messaging middleware libraries you mentioned always create a queue and an exchange matching that queue, then bind them together. By doing that, they enable you to "publish" a message to the particular exchange that is bound to the queue of your consumer, so you get the *send* functionality.

So, under the hood, it is still publish-subscribe.

**Using a library or do things yourself**

Setting up queues and exchanges is tedious work. There're surely some cases where you want to take control on low level and take care of all those things from code.

However, using messaging middleware, would it be EasyNetQ, MassTransit or NServiceBus is extremely valuable. All of those libraries have comprehensive topology management capabilities that enable developers to concentrate on delivering value instead of dealing with exchanges and queues.

In many cases using type-based routing, as each of those libraries does, makes perfect sense.

Here I give you a quick list of things you'd need to do in your code, or manually if you choose not to use a messaging middleware library:

- Configuring the topology
- Configure routing
- Handling exceptions using retries and redelivery
- Controlling scoped dependencies for message consumers
- Logging and tracing
- Scheduling
- Long-running processes and distributed transactions

The list if by far not comprehensive, but it gives you the idea. If you're ready to take care of all those concerns yourself - go for it.

Comment: Completely agree, MassTransit was designed to configure the broker topology through code. External scripts, etc. are ancient history. It's why we have database migrations now with EF, the code is always right. RabbitMQ has broker-level policies that can be used to apply control where necessary.

Comment: Hi Alexey thank you for your answer. However you have misunderstood my diagram. I never mentioned that the Producer will put messages directly into consumer queues? The `message broker (rabbitmq)` mean't the exchange setup. I will update my question.

Comment: In response to Chris, I feel your approach makes things tightly coupled. This explains it correctly https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/rabbitmq-who-creates-the-queues-and-exchanges/

Comment: I feel No.4 in the article makes more sense. You can't keep updating the code (publisher / consumer) with additions of exchange and queues and then redeploy every time there is change? May fine in a small environment. But will be a hassle once things get bigger.

Comment: @KJSR for me, the `message broker` is the infrastructure piece. so, I'd rather write `exchange` there, because it is now a mix of logical (consumer, queue) and physical (message broker) entities.
Concerning the "small" vs "large" systems, I can ensure you that both me and Chris are involved in developing _very_ large systems and I am very happy that the topoligy setup concern is something I _never_ need to touch.